# Imagemagick Texture padding/dilation like Adobe Painter or Xnormal

Tags: image, imagemagick, 2d, textures

Is it possible achieve a similar padding or dilation solution on textures with Imagemagick for non textured parts(alpha).

[Padding gif](https://substance3d.adobe.com/documentation/spdoc/files/134643719/134643714/1/1441715499000/padding.gif)

I've been looking at morphology functions but with no success. I would want to have a similar interpolation of pixels between two islands. I did find few forums where people are just stretching the pixels in x or y with multiple iterations but it doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: Perhaps https://imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#sparse_fill

Comment: I think what you want is inpainting.  See http://im.snibgo.com/fillholespri.htm and http://im.snibgo.com/fillholes.htm